# Glib segfault g_free hash table

Tags: c, glib

I'm not quite sure why if I try to free the data I get segfault. Any help will be appreciate it.

```
struct mystu {
  char *q;
};

static GHashTable *hashtable;

static void add_inv(char *q)
{
    gpointer old_key, old_value;

    if(!g_hash_table_lookup_extended(hashtable, q, &old_key, &old_value)){
        g_hash_table_insert(hashtable, g_strdup(q), GINT_TO_POINTER(10));
    }else{
        (old_value)++;
        g_hash_table_insert(hashtable, g_strdup(q), old_value);
        g_hash_table_remove (hashtable, q); // segfault
        g_free(old_key);   // segfault
        g_free(old_value); // segfault
    }   
}
...
int main(int argc, char *argv[]){
  hashtable = g_hash_table_new(g_str_hash, g_str_equal);
  ...
  struct mystu stu;
  add_inv(stu.q);
  g_hash_table_destroy(hashtable);
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In this example that you have shown and the endless battle for segfault, you have not malloc'd or new'd the memory for the variable `q`...for some reason you have skipped showing the code for `add_inv` within your `main` function.... the clue is on the pointer to char i.e. `q`, has that got `malloc`d memory...

Have you tried it this way:

```
int main(int argc, char *argv[]){
  const char *qInit = "foo";
  char *q;
  hashtable = g_hash_table_new(g_str_hash, g_str_equal);
  ...
  q = strdup(qInit); /* Now q has memory allocated! */

  add_inv(q); /* This should work */

  g_hash_table_destroy(hashtable);
}
```

A seg-fault occurs when you tried to de-reference memory that has not being `malloc`d nor `new`d depending on C/C++ respectively....it can happen if you `free`d or `delete`d a pointer that has not being `free`d or `new`d....

Comment: Thanks. I did as you indicated and seems to be working. Now I can remove that entry from the hash table g_hash_table_remove (hashtable, q); and g_free(old_key); but for some reason g_free(old_value); gives segfault.

Comment: @Mike: was old_value malloc'd or new'd?